# submit button is not working in zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am working on zend form and fieldsets. I have created form along with the submit button. Here is the code:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Search Results',
            'id'    => 'submit',
            'class' => 'submitme',
        ),
    ));
```

I can see all my fieldsets on view side. But, I cannot see submit button.
Here is my controller file code:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager')->get('Client\Form\Search\SearchForm');
return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
```

And finally this is the code for view:

```
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag($form);
```

Comment: Why are you using Super lazy functions why dont you properly echo all form rows and see what is missing

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss out the part to assign an action for your form

```
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post')
     ->setAttribute('action', $this->url())
     ->prepare();
```

Comment: It's like this:

`$this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
        ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(FALSE))
        ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());`

Comment: Had to edit my post. You need to assign an action for your form - no action assigned means no action attribute. No action attribute means form post will not work - that's html :D

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this (as mentioned by sam) you need to set attributes

```
   $Form = $this->Form;
$Form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('(your route name here)', array('action' => 'add', 'controller' => '(your controller name here)')));
$Form->prepare();

  echo $this->form()->openTag($Form);
 echo $this->formSubmit($Form->get('any other feilds that you want to see'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($Form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```